# Drupal workflow

Tags: drupal, workflow

I need to implement a workflow in my Drupal website. I have a simple workflow:

1. contributer: Who create nodes in draft status saves new versions of a node
2. publisher: Do the same as the contributer and change the state of the draft node to published status.

I'm confused between Maestro, Workbench and Workflow modules.
Does anyone know which one is the most appropriate in my case?
Thank you very much.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

For this approach no need any Contributor module.Login as admin give the create permission to the normal user(may be fall under some roles) expect "administer nodes".If we disable this permission to the particular role who will not get a option to publish the content.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Workflow module http://drupal.org/project/workflow.

1) What you need is to create workflow.
2) Create workflow states
3) Give required state change roles to the roles
4) Go to the Permissions, remove all permissions from the Node, for you will give them in the workflow settings page